# How to allow iframe embed for a web page? (The iframe shows blank screen)

Tags: javascript, html, nginx, iframe

I'm trying to put a url from my web app in an iframe to be displayed on another website.

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://mywebsite.com/a-page"></iframe>
```

But right now the page doesn't show up inside the iframe. It's completely blank. Some internet research shows that it means my web app is not set up to allow iframes. What should I do (e.g. change certain settings on my server) to allow iframe embed?

I only want to allow certain url patterns from my web app to be embeddable, i.e. https://mywebsite/embeds/page-number. The site is built with react.js and using Nginx server.

Answer (score 0):

The client (browser in this case) is blocking the web site from being rendered. You have to whitelist the origin from which you are trying to access the content to be loaded in the iframe

If you open dev tools, you should see something like this

[image: Content security policy image]

This article should provide the solution you are looking for to fix your issue :
[Google Content Security Policy](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/csp/)

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't seem like a practical solution. Other websites need to be able to embed my webpage without having to whitelist my site every time. Everyone can embed iframes from sites like Youtube and Spotify with no additional whitelisting. I'd like people to do the same with my site.